# Native crash android boot-framework.so

Tags: xamarin, crash

I have an app and it's crashing, this only happen on Samsung devices
A5 2016 android 7.0 and Samsung J7Pro Android 7.0, the app is made with xamarin, target sdk 7.0, the error ocurr when I back from one activity to other but it happend randomly, most of the time works fine just crash 2-3 times day

```
12-14 15:46:51.832 F/DEBUG   ( 7756): backtrace:
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #00 pc 0008ef00  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #01 pc 028d10fb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.RenderNode.nGetTransformMatrix+102)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #02 pc 028d360b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.RenderNode.getMatrix+62)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #03 pc 026aa667  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.View.getMatrix+82)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #04 pc 028b47dd  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild+96)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #05 pc 026ad64b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.View.invalidateInternal+382)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #06 pc 026ad2bd  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.View.invalidate+96)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #07 pc 0299535b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.widget.ProgressBar.invalidateDrawable+158)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #08 pc 0202cdf3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf+62)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #09 pc 0225c717  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable$1.invalidateDrawable+42)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #10 pc 0202cdf3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf+62)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #11 pc 0202d523  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setVisible+62)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #12 pc 022620ed  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable.setVisible+152)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #13 pc 02995ead  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.widget.ProgressBar.onVisibilityAggregated+120)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #14 pc 026a2daf  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow+538)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #15 pc 028adb5d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow+184)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #16 pc 028adb5d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow+184)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #17 pc 028adb5d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow+184)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #18 pc 028adb5d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow+184)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #19 pc 028adb5d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow+184)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #20 pc 028adb5d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow+184)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #21 pc 028adb5d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow+184)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #22 pc 028adb5d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow+184)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #23 pc 02903d31  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals+780)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #24 pc 02909f69  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal+148)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #25 pc 028f909d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run+40)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #26 pc 0286bf7b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run+158)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #27 pc 0286db61  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks+556)
12-14 15:46:51.833 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #28 pc 0286e2a1  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.Choreographer.doFrame+1364)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #29 pc 0286c971  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run+60)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #30 pc 01f4d6c1  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.os.Handler.handleCallback+44)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #31 pc 01f4d723  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+54)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #32 pc 025e0c8d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.os.Looper.loop+696)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #33 pc 01f5fe63  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (android.app.ActivityThread.main+598)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #34 pc 000a9341  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #35 pc 00407d61  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+228)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #36 pc 000b065f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+182)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #37 pc 00316feb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+58)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #38 pc 0031835f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12InvokeMethodERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectS4_S4_j+766)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #39 pc 002bea3d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Method_invokeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_S3_+40)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #40 pc 00606159  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x56f000) (java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke+116)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #41 pc 02b84d19  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+100)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #42 pc 02b8636d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ec9000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+1680)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #43 pc 000a9341  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #44 pc 00407d61  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+228)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #45 pc 000b065f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+182)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #46 pc 00316feb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+58)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #47 pc 00316dfb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+266)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #48 pc 00278bf7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+426)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #49 pc 0006a5dd  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #50 pc 0006c0cf  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcRKNS_6VectorINS_7String8EEEb+510)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #51 pc 00002e67  /system/bin/app_process32
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #52 pc 00016d79  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
12-14 15:46:51.834 F/DEBUG   ( 7756):     #53 pc 0000295c  /system/bin/app_process32
12-14 15:46:51.892 I/Finsky  (23013): [15873] com.google.android.finsky.bn.an.run(6): Stats for Executor: InstallBackgroundThread com.google.android.finsky.bn.ao@ff0418d[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
12-14 15:46:51.893 I/Finsky  (23013): [15873] com.google.android.finsky.bn.an.run(6): Stats for Executor: Db-install_service com.google.android.finsky.bn.ao@d530f42[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
12-14 15:46:51.894 I/Finsky  (23013): [15873] com.google.android.finsky.bn.an.run(6): Stats for Executor: InstallBackgroundThread com.google.android.finsky.bn.ao@a0fcb53[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
12-14 15:46:51.906 D/CustomFrequencyManagerService( 4053): releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1352000  uid : 1000  pid : 4053  tag : AMS_ACT_RESUME@CPU_MIN@26
12-14 15:46:51.907 D/ActivityManagerPerformance( 4053): AMP_release() ACT_RESUME
12-14 15:46:51.960 E/Watchdog( 4053): !@Sync 3115 [2018-12-14 15:46:51.959]
12-14 15:46:52.020 I/Finsky  (23013): [15873] com.google.android.finsky.bn.an.run(6): Stats for Executor: InstallQueueDatabaseManager com.google.android.finsky.bn.ao@ddf0c90[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 53]
12-14 15:46:52.131 I/Finsky  (23013): [15873] com.google.android.finsky.bn.an.run(6): Stats for Executor: Db-scheduler_logging_store.db com.google.android.finsky.bn.ao@52c6989[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 4]
12-14 15:46:52.248 I/Finsky  (23013): [15873] com.google.android.finsky.bn.an.run(6): Stats for Executor: VerifyAppsDataStore com.google.android.finsky.bn.ao@506dd8e[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 69]
12-14 15:46:52.249 I/Finsky  (23013): [15873] com.google.android.finsky.bn.an.run(6): Stats for Executor: Db-verify_apps.db com.google.android.finsky.bn.ao@541c9af[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 81]
12-14 15:46:52.790 E/        ( 7756): ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
12-14 15:46:52.790 E/        ( 7756): sys.mobilecare.preload = false
```

Comment: Is it always a similar trace? From what you've posted it seems like ProgressBar does something to make it go . Do you have any code that you can show us for that part of the code?

Comment: I dont have a ProgressBar but I have a ProgressDialog

Comment: if (IsFinishing || IsDestroyed) return;
    if (_progressDialog == null)
    {
     CreateDialog();
    }

    if (_progressDialog.IsShowing)
     _progressDialog.Dismiss();
    _progressDialog.SetMessage(message);
    _progressDialog.SetTitle(title);
    _progressDialog.Show();